# Chain queryOrderedByValue() and queryOrderedByKey()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

I am using this table to generate real-time search updates for my `searchBar` and I want to make the following things:

1. If a user searches for "dsa", show him the results for "dsa". (**Done**)

   ```
   ref.queryOrderedByKey()
           .queryStarting(atValue: queryLower)
           .queryEnding(atValue: queryLower + "\u{f8ff}")
   ...
   ```
2. User will be able to select from which table the results to be shown so I embedded the table names as a value in order to search for them. I want, when a user selected the button *Search in Sports Center*, with a value of "dsa" to show him **only the "dsa" results that have a value of "sports center".**

To make this work I was thinking:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey()
            .queryStarting(atValue: queryLower)
            .queryEnding(atValue: queryLower + "\u{f8ff}")
            .queryOrderedByValue()
            .queryEqual(toValue: tableName)
...
```

The problem is that it crashed on `.queryOrderedByValue`. Seems like you can't chain query ordering or I don't know how.

How can I make this work or is it a better architecture I can employ to solve my problem?

Comment: You can only `orderBy` one type of element you can't `orderByKey` and `orderByValue` with Firebase.

You'll need to filter your results on the front-end in order to run additional queries.

Comment: As sketchthat says, a Firebase Database query can only contain a single `queryOrderedBy...` clause. It may be possible to combine the two values that you're trying to filter on into a single property, e.g. `"value_key": "sports center_dsadasda"` and then filter on that. For more on this and other options, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase